# MacVim switching tabs & El Capitan split screen

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, macvim, osx-el-capitan

Using El Capitan's split screen feature, I'd like to have MacVim open in the left half and Terminal open in the right half.

This works fine, until I try to switch tabs in MacVim via the keyboard shortcuts like `⌘+}` and `⌘+{`. When I do that, suddenly the MacVim side now takes up ~80% of the screen instead of ~50%. Why?